# How to add HIViewRef as subview/view to a new Carbon Window?

Tags: macos-carbon

I created a Carbon window using CreateNewWindow() which will return me a WindowRef. 
I create a HIViewRef and now I want to add it to the newly created WindowRef.

Can anyone please help me with this issue? How can I add HIViewRef to a WindowRef which does not have any subviews?

Thanks,

Dheeraj.

Answer (score 2):

HIViewRef and ControlRef are the same, so to add HIViewRef to WindowRef you could use something like:

```
HIViewRef root_control;
GetRootControl (winref, &root_control);
HIViewAddSubview(root_control, hiview);
```